# How do I use iexact to check if an item matches case-insensitively in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use `iexact` in my Django app.

I have items in my database like `test`, `TEST`, `tEsT`, and `TesT`.

I'm trying to find out if any form of `test` is my database. It seems like I need to use `iexact` but however I try to use it I'm getting an error.

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
def item_search(x):
    item = x.column_in_database

    if test__iexact = 'test' in item:
       return 1; #this is just pseduocode for stackoverflow
    elif
       return 0; #this is just pseduocode for stackoverflow
```

I've tried a variety of ways but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: your question is unclear to me -- is "x" an instance of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *very* confused.

`__iexact` is something you use in Django query filters. Django converts that to the relevant SQL when it sends the query to the database. It's not a Python keyword, you can't just say `test__iexact` in a statement and expect it to work.

The usual way of doing case-insensitive matching in normal code is just to convert both sides to the same case, ie lower:

```
if 'test' in item.lower():
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro) as keyword arguments to Django method calls, you can't use them elsewhere in your code. Django does extra work to translate a string separated by `__` into a field name and type of lookup, and Python doesn't know how to do that.

What you're looking for is probably something like:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(column_in_database__iexact = 'test')

if queryset: # there is at least one object that matches
    return 1
else: 
    return 0
```

Which will match `'TEST'` but not `'mytest'`. If you also want to match `'mytest'`, use `__icontains` instead, which is also case-insensitive.

If you want to match against an object already retrieved from the database with `get` or similar, then you can use:

```
if 'test' == item.text_column_in_database.lower():
```

or, if you want to match `'mytest'`:

```
if 'test' in item.text_column_in_database.lower():
```

Comment: actually icontains in case-insensitive.

Comment: @UkuLoskit Thanks, that was an inconvenient typo.